# How do i loop over input to make my 1-bit multiplexer module act like its 5-bit

Tags: verilog, test-bench

Please forgive me i've only started to learn this today
Im trying to make a 8x1 multiplexer using structural model in Verilog, it's supposed to take 8 ports and it's a 1-bit multiplexer, however i want to make it so it takes each input as a 5 bit,

I have tried in my test bench to loop over the 5 bits  8 inputs and change the input of the multiplexer 5 times, and take the 1-bit output and put it in its appropriate index in the result,
however the result always returns the initial value assigned to it only which is 00000,
what am i doing wrong? it the logic behind this correct?

```
wire out;
output reg [4:0] result;
reg [4:0] result0, result1,result2,result3,result4,result5,result6,result7;
mux name(.d0(d0), .d1(d1), .d2(d2), .d3(d3), .d4(d4), .d5(d5), .d6(d6), .d7(d7), .s0(s0), .s1(s1), .s2(s2), .out(out));
initial begin
result0 =5'b00000;
result1 =5'b00001;
result2 =5'b00010;
result3 =5'b00011;
result4 =5'b00100;
result5 =5'b00101;
result6 =5'b00110;
result7 =5'b00111;
assign result =5'b00000;
for (i=0;i<5;i=i+1)begin
     d0=result0[i];
     d1=result1[i];
     d2=result2[i];
     d3=result3[i];
     d4=result4[i];
     d5=result5[i];
     d6=result6[i];
     d7=result7[i];
     #10
     result[i]=out;
end 
end
```

Comment: If you observe your `for` loop, you are basically driving d0-d7 nets repeatedly i.e. first you assign `d0 = result0[0]` then `d0 = result0[1]` In the end `d0` will settle to `result0[4]` which is zero. Same applies for d1 to d7.

Answer (score 0):

It's great that you learn something new, so let's take a look on the code.

First thing is that you declare the result an output. This is not wrong per se, but usually a testbench is the highest layer and you don't want to output the result vector. So just change the type to reg.

```
reg [4:0] result;
```

The signals d1 to d7 are not declared explicitly. Recommended is declaring them the same way you did for for result0 to result7.

```
reg d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7;
```

The same applies to your select signals S0 to S2

```
reg s0, s1, s2;
```

These are the cosmetic things, but they help to read the code easier.

Now to functionality.
These select signals are not driven in the code you provide, therefore, they will be initialized with 0. Consequently the mux will always forward result0 to its output.